# Why gRPC replace exception when leaving context?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

The essence of the question is this - there is a gateway where the request comes, then it calls the necessary service In the gateway there is a global exception interceptor There is a service in which an exception is thrown

Exception:

```cs
public class RequiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException : RpcException
{
    private string _requestId;
    private string _originalRequestId;

    public string RequestId
    {
        get { return _requestId; }

        private set { _requestId = value; }
    }
    public string? OriginalRequestId
    {
        get { return _originalRequestId; }

        private set { _originalRequestId = value; }
    }

    public RequiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException(Status status, string requestId, string? originalRequestId) : base(status)
    {
        _requestId = requestId;
        _originalRequestId = originalRequestId ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

In the service itself, it contains information and fields and it walks calmly through the service, however, going beyond the context of this service and returning to the gateway, something changes the exception to the base RpcException, respectively, the stack trace and data are lost, but Status is transmitted and I can throw one Response Trailer there (apparently there is a limit of 3 the element is worth it, because if there are more than 3 of them, grpc already gives the answer 500), but I would not like to put a huge json there and then disassemble it.
Actually, why is this happening? And how to deal with this?
p.s. I know that grpc has only one exception

Interceptor:

```cs
public class GrpcErrorHandler : Interceptor
{
    public override async Task<TResponse> UnaryServerHandler<TRequest, TResponse>(
        TRequest request,
        ServerCallContext context,
        UnaryServerMethod<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
    {
        try
        {
            return await continuation(request, context);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            switch (e)
            {
                case RequiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException requiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException:
                    context.ResponseTrailers.Add(new Metadata.Entry("requestId", requiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException?.Data?["requestId"]?.ToString() ?? ""));
                    context.ResponseTrailers.Add(new Metadata.Entry("originalRequestId", requiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException?.Data?["originalRequestId"]?.ToString() ?? "")); //почему-то есть в контексте сервиса, но, выходя за рамки - теряется.
                    throw new RequiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException(requiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException!.Status, requiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException?.Data?["requestId"]?.ToString() ?? "", requiredPropertyIsNullOrEmptyException?.Data?["originalRequestId"]?.ToString());
            }
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to throw currently exception (without new), tried to create base gRPC exception

```cs
    private static RpcException HandleRpcException(RpcException exception, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        var trailers = exception.Trailers;
        trailers.Add(new Metadata.Entry("test2","test12"));
        return new RpcException(new Status(StatusCode.Unknown, "details"), trailers);
    }
```

I expect that the data from the exception will be passed to the main service, and not lost when exiting the context.